# Pandas add values in the right time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two DataFrames indexed by the Date, on one DataFrame the rows change hourly on the other one it changes (sometimes it changes every 5 minutes sometimes it has a different step).

```
>>> print df2['value']
date
2015-10-06 09:00:00    0.612303
2015-10-06 10:00:00    0.482605
2015-10-06 11:00:00    0.604132

>>> print df1['value']
date
2015-10-06 09:05:00    0.412303
2015-10-06 09:08:00    0.112303
2015-10-06 09:28:00    0.012303
2015-10-06 10:15:00    0.000005
2015-10-06 11:00:00    0.133132
```

I want the `df1` values that are between hour h and h+1 to have the corresponding `df2` value.

Wanted result:

```
>>> print df1['value']
date
2015-10-06 09:05:00    0.612303
2015-10-06 09:08:00    0.612303
2015-10-06 09:28:00    0.612303
2015-10-06 10:15:00    0.482605
2015-10-06 11:00:00    0.604132
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#merging-asof) exists for this purpose.

Comment: @ajcr that solved my problem. Thanks, do you want to write an answer for me to accept?

Comment: I've added an answer using `merge_asof` below - let me know if you'd like any more detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#merging-asof) to generate a correct column of values for your example with a DatetimeIndex:

```
pd.merge_asof(df1.reset_index(), # see note about reset_index below
              df2.reset_index(),
              on='date', 
              tolerance=pd.Timedelta('1H'))
```

The tolerance parameter allows you to specify up to how long after a particular time the merge should be valid. For instance, if we specify `tolerance=pd.Timedelta('10m')` (10 minutes), not all of the values can merged and some locations are marked `NaN` instead.

---

Note that I had to reset the index of the two frames before merging. I wanted to merge using `left_index=True` and `right_index=True`, but pandas refuses to allow this when also passing in a tolerance parameter (this is possibly a bug - using `merge_asof` should be even neater here if changed).

Comment: FWIW I've opened an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15135)

Comment: ...and a [bug fix](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/15139) has been merged into master. Should be fixed in the next release of pandas.

Answer (score 1):

For Pandas version 0.19.0 or better, see [ajcr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41660879/190597).

---

For Pandas versions < 0.19.0: You could combine the two DataFrames, with `concat`, use `ffill` to forward-fill the NaN values with the desired values, and then `update` `df1` with those values:

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'value':[0.612303,0.482605,0.604132]}, index=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2015-10-06 09:00:00', '2015-10-06 10:00:00', '2015-10-06 11:00:00']))
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'value':[0.412303, 0.112303, 0.012303, 0.000005, 0.133132]}, index=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2015-10-06 09:05:00', '2015-10-06 09:08:00', '2015-10-06 09:28:00', '2015-10-06 10:15:00', '2015-10-06 11:00:00']))

df1.update(pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).ffill().iloc[:, 1])
print(df1)
```

yields

```
                        value
2015-10-06 09:05:00  0.612303
2015-10-06 09:08:00  0.612303
2015-10-06 09:28:00  0.612303
2015-10-06 10:15:00  0.482605
2015-10-06 11:00:00  0.604132
```

---

Alternatively, you could use `searchsorted` to find the index values which indicate where `df1.index` fits into `df2.index`:

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'value':[0.612303,0.482605,0.604132]}, index=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2015-10-06 09:00:00', '2015-10-06 10:00:00', '2015-10-06 11:00:00']))
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'value':[0.412303, 0.112303, 0.012303, 0.000005, 0.133132]}, index=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2015-10-06 09:05:00', '2015-10-06 09:08:00', '2015-10-06 09:28:00', '2015-10-06 10:15:00', '2015-10-06 11:00:00']))

df1['value'] = df2.iloc[df2.index.searchsorted(df1.index, side='right')-1].values
print(df1)
```

yields

```
                        value
2015-10-06 09:05:00  0.612303
2015-10-06 09:08:00  0.612303
2015-10-06 09:28:00  0.612303
2015-10-06 10:15:00  0.482605
2015-10-06 11:00:00  0.604132
```

Note that `searchsorted` assumes that `df2.index` is already in sorted order. If it is not, then use `df2 = df2.sort_index()` first.

In contrast, `pd.concat` returns a DataFrame whose DatatimeIndex is in sorted
order, even if `df1.index` and/or `df2.index` is not in sorted order. So for the first method calling `sort_index` is not necessary.

---

Of these two methods, `searchsorted` is faster. For example, with this setup:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
N = 1000
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(N), index=pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=N, freq='14T'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(int(N/60*14)), index=pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=int(N/60*14), freq='1H'))
df3, df4 = df1.copy(), df1.copy()

df3.update(pd.concat([df3, df2], axis=1).ffill().iloc[:, 1])
df4[0] = df2.iloc[df2.index.searchsorted(df4.index, side='right')-1].values
assert df3.equals(df4)
```

`searchsorted` is ~2.8x faster:

```
In [88]: %timeit df3.update(pd.concat([df3, df2], axis=1).ffill().iloc[:, 1])
100 loops, best of 3: 2.13 ms per loop

In [89]: %timeit df4[0] = df2.iloc[df2.index.searchsorted(df4.index, side='right')-1].values
1000 loops, best of 3: 744 µs per loop

In [90]: len(df1), len(df2)
Out[90]: (1000, 233)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your df1 create a new column "hourly" from its index
Then simply join df1 with df2 on this new created column to add the values from df2.

Will post code asap :)

EDIT: as promised, here is the code

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df1 = pd.read_csv("df1.csv",index_col="date", parse_dates=True)
df2 = pd.read_csv("df2.csv",index_col="date", parse_dates=True)


def fromTimeStampToHour(date):
    datetimeObj = date.to_datetime()
    hourlyObj = datetime(year=datetimeObj.year,month= datetimeObj.month, day = datetimeObj.day, hour=datetimeObj.hour)
    return hourlyObj

df1["Hours"] = df1.index.map(lambda x: fromTimeStampToHour(x))

print pd.merge(left=df1,  right=df2, left_on="Hours", right_index=True, suffixes=("_df1", "_df2"))
```